Generation of Reactive WebClients from WSDL files using WebFlux
I have a WSDL file defining a SOAP service, and I'm looking to generate a Reactive (WebFlux) client from it.
In the past, I've successfully generated Reactive WebClients for JSON REST services using the Maven plugin openapi-generator-maven-plugin.
However, I'm unable to find any tools to achieve the same for SOAP services from a WSDL file. Could someone provide guidance or suggest any Maven plugins or tools that can assist in generating Reactive WebClients from WSDL files?

I'm not aware of any library that supports generating reactive clients. Maybe use Apache CXF for generating source code and than use a library like Spring WS to write your own SOAP client.
